# css: how to position a X sign at the top right corner of the img element

Tags: html, css, css-float

Besides, position: relative, and then set right and bottom position?

I wanna the close sign positioned top right corner whatever the size of the img

Comment: `position:absolute; top:0; right:0;` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use absolute position on the X sign and set its position with respect to the relatively positioned parent.

```js
document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('close');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.close:before {
  content: '✕';
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
  <span class="close"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the `<img>` in another element with `position: relative` and place the X sign as a sibling to the image. Then give the X sign `position: absolute` and `top` and `right` values of `0` or whatever.

You'll also need to make sure the image is either `width: 100%` and/or the wrapping element is `floated` or has `display: inline-block`.

**Example markup:**

```
<div class="parent">
  <img src="image.jpg">
  <button class="close">X</button>
</div>
```

**Example CSS:**

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Here's a pen of this: http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/FjeuD/